# Phantomjs using page.evaluate outside page.open

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to inject a command to the webpage to simulate a key press.

On page.open, i have an event handler that looks to see if the webpage has completed loading, as a console message.

Then using:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) { }
```

I look to see if that is the msg returned. Inside this onconsole message I call a page.evaluate function to simulate the key press, however nothing seems to be happening.

Can this be done? or does the page.evaluate need to be inside the page.open request.

### Code

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    var phantomCommand = null;
    //console.log(msg);
    try {
        phantomCommand = JSON.parse(msg);
    }
    catch(e) {
    }

    if(phantomCommand != null) {
        switch(phantomCommand.command) {
            case "PageChangeCompleted":
                for ( var a in this.actions) {
                    if ( profile == a ) {
                    for ( var la in this.actions[a] ) {
                        var nextAction = this.actions[a][la];
                    if ( nextAction.action == 'keyPress' ) {
                        keyCode = this.clientInfo.keyCodes[nextAction.key];
                        console.log("# Send key press " + nextAction.key + " with keyCode " + keyCode);
                        page.evaluate(function(keyCode) {
                                var event = {
                                    keyCode: keyCode
                                };
                                event.preventDefault = function(){};
                                KeyHandler.KeyPressed(event);
                            }, keyCode);
                    } else if ( nextAction.action == 'waitForPageChange') {
                        var output = "/tmp/" + profile + ".png";
                        page.render(output);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}


//console.log("Initialized " + ip);

page.open(url, function(status) {page
    console.log("opened "+ ip + " to URL "+url);
    page.evaluate(function(ip, mac, serial, next) {
    ASTB.IpAddress = ip;
    ASTB.MacAddress = mac;
    ASTB.Serial = serial;
    Portal.PageChangeCompleted.AddHandler(function(e) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({
            command: "PageChangeCompleted",
            page: e.params.page,
            params: e.params.params,
            index: next
        }));
    });
    }, ip, mac, serial, next);
    //console.log("PageChangeCompleted")

});
```

Comment: It's not great practice to overload event handlers to do unexpected things. It may work (although in your case it doesn't appear to be, hence your question :) ), but it causes headaches when you or someone else is caught by surprise in the future.

If you're open to using the experimental PhantomJS `onCallback` handler (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-onCallback), add a `documentReady` handler that in turn calls `window.callPhantom()`.

Of course, this is an experimental API, but it's been in Phantom since 1.6. I've used it on a couple of projects.

Comment: Problem is, im using this for load testing on one of our products that are already existing and obviously cant add code to be included in the product. Someone had something similar before, however I am doing it on a much larger scale using the similar functionality, dont think onCallBack is what i am looking for.

Comment: Maybe use `page.evaluate()` to inject your keypress code inside a `documentReady` handler? That way, you're guaranteed that it won't fire until the document is loaded, and you don't overload `onConsoleMessage` in unexpected ways. Of course, none of this addresses what might be a totally separate issue with the keypress handler.

Comment: @user2373636 Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, apologies haven’t been on here for a while. The key handler was being called before the page had fully loaded, I didn't realise the product under test has a method that can be called to ensure the page had finished loading.